# FeignClient OAuth2 StackOverFlow Exception

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-feign

I need to add a authorization-header in each request, which will be executed from my feign client. Token, which I have to use, has to be fetched first from other service and it expires in 20 min.

1. When I'm starting "getClient"-Request, I need to send 'authorization' Header, which expires in 20 min.

```
@FeignClient(name = "myClient", url = "${my.service}")
@Headers("backend-authorization: {header}")
public interface MyClient {
    @PostMapping(
            value = "/client",
            consumes = "application/json")
    String getClient(@RequestBody String client);

}
```

This is my FeignConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients
public class FeignConfig {

    private TokenService tokenService;

   public FeignConfig(@Lazy TokenService tokenService) {
       //THIS TOKEN-SERVICES USES FEIGN-CLIENT WO FETCHTING NEW TOKEN
        this.tokenService = tokenService;
    }

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }

    @Bean
    Logger myLogger() {
        return new FeignLogger();
    }
    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient client() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
       return requestTemplate -> {
           //fetchToken() makes rest-call with other feignClient
           requestTemplate.header("authorization", "Bearer " +  tokenService.fetchToken());
       };
    }
}
```

My FeignConfig uses a services, which invokes other FeignClient:

```
@Component
public class TokenService {
  
    //TokenClient is a FeignClient
    private TokenClient client;

    public TokenService(TokenClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    /**
    * client is alos a FeignClient
    */
    public String fetchToken() {
        String accessToken = client.getToken(new TokenRequest());
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

And here is a FeignClient for fetching token:

```
@FeignClient(name = "token", url = "${my.token.endpoint}")
@Headers("backend-authorization: {header}")
public interface TokenClient {
    @PostMapping(value = "/token",
        consumes = "application/json")
    String getToken(@RequestBody TokenRequest request);

}
```

So I don't even get a 4xx Exception, after a while a get StackOverflow Exception.
Maybe there are better approaches, as I chose.